# Run Microsoft.Speech over IIS?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-server-2008, speech-recognition, speech

I have an app that uses Microsoft.Speech to recognize speech in a WAV file. It works perfectly when run locally as a console app but barfs when executed by IIS.

Assuming I have the following installed on WinServer 2008 with .NET 3.5+:

1. Microsoft Speech Platform - Software Development Kit (SDK) (Version 10.1)
2. Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime Languages (Version 10.1)
3. Microsoft Speech Platform - Software Development Kit (SDK) (Version 10.1)

Is it even possible to use Microsoft.Speech over IIS7? What am I missing here?

I've tried re-coding it as an ASP.NET web service but that doesn't work either.

Suuuuper stuck here. Thanks if you can help :) Pretty please :)

**UPDATE:**
Here's the error message + stack trace:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.ISpRecognizer.CreateRecoContext(ISpRecoContext& ppNewCtxt) 
at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiRecognizer.<>c__DisplayClass17.b__16() 
at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiProxy.PassThrough.Invoke(ObjectDelegate pfn) 
at Microsoft.Speech.Internal.SapiInterop.SapiRecognizer.CreateRecoContext() 
at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.RecognizerBase.Initialize(SapiRecognizer recognizer, Boolean inproc) 
at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.get_RecoBase() 
at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.Initialize(RecognizerInfo recognizerInfo) 
at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine..ctor() 
at myRecognize.Recognize..cctor() The type initializer for 'myRecognize.Recognize' threw an exception. myRecognize 
at myRecognize.Recognize.get_Reco() 
at myRecognize.Recognize.Listen(String wavLoc, String grammars)
```

Comment: When you go to a doctor for diagnosis.. you gotto tell him symptoms. Why don't you write error/exception you are seeing? Is it taking too much of time (timeout error)? Where is your wav file (for read permission issue)?

Comment: I'll try to update with an error message shortly... Thanks!

Comment: The exception I'm getting is this:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). I get this even if i ONLY try to set the grammar with Reco.LoadGrammar(Grammar), where Reco is my Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine and Grammar is my grammar built from GrammarBuilder().

Comment: Try using procmon to find where the Access is denied is happening: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Also do you have the SAPI SDK installed?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark: it's trying and failing to load some files from disk, from an area the IIS app pool user doesn't have permission to read.

Try running sysinternals [ProcessMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out which, then grant the app pool user (or local group IIS_IUSRS if you haven't changed the app pool user) permissions to that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to use ProcessMon but it spits out so many records and I'm not sure what to filter for. I tried filtering for only error messages involving my speech recognition .exe but can't really single anything out. Have any suggestions for what I should look for?

Comment: Filter on Result is ACCESS DENIED? I'm not sure what the IIS process is on 2008 sorry.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look. Thanks for your help... I'll report back.

Comment: I'm wondering if my problem is related to Partially Trusted Caller settings. I'm aware that several parts of Microsoft.Speech are only allowed by fully-trusted callers. Here's an article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/02/04/367390.aspx I'll try this too.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix: Grant read/write access to `C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\appdata\roaming` for the same user that the app pool is running under.